# AND is not returning result in GraphQL

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, grandstack, neo4j-graphql-js

I am trying to write a query with AND operator to extract data from neo4j in GraphQL but it doesn't return any result. I am using neo4j-graphql-js library. I have the following schema

```
type Order {
    label: String
    id: String
    details: [OrderDetails] @relation(name: "RELATED_TO", direction: "OUT")
}

type OrderDetails {
    createdBy: String
    label: String
    oId: String
}
```

Following is the query:

```
{
  Order(filter: { AND: [{ label: "fruits", details: {label: "banana"} }] }) {
    label
  }
}
```

I also tried this:

```
{
  Order(filter: {  label: "fruits", details: {label: "banana"}  }) {
    label
  }
}
```

But these two queries do not return any result.
If I just write **label: "fruits"** without AND it returns the result but I want all orders of fruit which are particularly for banana.
Any suggestion where I am getting wrong?

Comment: I think you can break the filtering into two parts, 1) fruits and then with banana.

Comment: No that doesn't help. That query returns empty rows where the condition doesn'tt meet with banana.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have mentioned about using neo4j-graphql-js library. You can do something like this:

```
{
  Order(
    filter: { label: "fruits", details_single: { label: "banana" } }
  ) {
    details {
      label
    }
  }
}
```